# Drupal Block PHP

Tags: php, drupal

Im created a custom block, with the below code, but im having some trouble turning the Group Title into an link, that will take the user back to the group at anytime.

Below is the code ive used, I thought active turns it into a link, but perhaps im being stupid.

```
  <div class="active"><h2><?php print $group_title; ?></h2></div>
```

Below is the full code:

```
<?php $group_title = og_get_group_context()->title; ?>
<?php $group_nid = og_get_group_context()->nid; ?>
<?php $forum_link = og_forum_get_forum_container($group_nid); ?>
<div class="active"><h2><?php print $group_title; ?></h2></div>
<div class="content"
    <div class="item-list">
        <ul>
            <li class="user-input-link"><a title="Add a new Forum topic"href="/node/add/forum?gids[]=<?php print $group_nid; ?>">Add a new forum topic</a>
          </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create URL for it to work.

Here is the link to API with more info: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l/6

```
<div class="active"><h2><?php print l($group_title, "node/{$group_nid}"); ?></h2></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an anchor tag, like:

```
<div><h2><a href="url_goes_here"><?php print $group_title; ?></a></h2></div>
```

I don't know how to get the url in Drupal though..